# First html DIV can be removed but further appended cannot

Tags: jquery

```
$('button').click(function() { $("ul").append('<div>').addClass("a");}); //Adding new DIVs

$('div').on('click',function() { $(this).replaceWith('');});  //Trying to remove them
```

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/galexj9/3y3d5k2o/) is my fiddle trying to simply create a DIV with the "Add New!" button and then later when the DIV is clicked on it is removed.
I tried using different commands for the removing part including using `.click();` instead of `.on();` and also using `.hide();` and `.html('');` and `.remove();` for the `.replaceWith('');`    All of which have successfully removed the FIRST div which is already coded onto the page but not any of the DIVs which are appended to the list.

Comment: try using `.remove()`

Comment: I just tried it now and it didn't help, I think it might be a problem that the appended DIVs aren't considered <div> tags in the code.

Comment: Have you tried anything?Why is Your fiddle empty? Show us your code

Answer (score 0):

While removing you cannot access the dynamically created divs like $('div')

it should be like below

Your HTML

```js
/* for adding div */

$('.addMore').click(function(){
  
  $('.appendHere').append('<div class="addedDiv"> Darth Vader is cool! </div>');
  
});

/* for removing */

$('.appendHere').on('click','.addedDiv',function(){
  
  /* for removing it */
  $(this).remove();
  
  /* for emptying it */
  $(this).html('');
  
});
```

```html
<div class="appendHere"></div>

<button class="addMore"> </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

**Html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button type="button">
Add New!   
</button>
<ul>

</ul>
```

**JQuery Code**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {    
     jQuery('button').click(function() {

     jQuery("ul").append('<div>test</div>').addClass("clickbox");
     }); //Adding new DIVs 

 jQuery( "body" ).on( "click", "div", function() {      
  jQuery(this).remove();//to remove 
});

});
```

**Css Code**

```
.clickbox {
    cursor: pointer;//to display div text clickable.
}
```

You can view [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/tenigada/fdpbmf84/)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/9fy22pup/).

Note: Appending a `div` inside `ul` is not a good practice. So I have created a `div.contents` inside which the dynamics `div`'s are getting appended.

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn">
    Add New!
</button>
<div class="contents"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    $('.btn').on('click', function () {
        $('.contents').append('<div class="a">New Div</div>');
    });
    $('body').on('click', '.a', function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```